# How to locate unpermitted params :id in active admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a `project` that has `buildings` that have `address`. When I create a building, no problems arise. When I edit the building, I get `Unpermitted parameter: :id`

In my building.rb:

```
permit_params :name, :construction_year, :floors, :building_type, :energy_label, :owner_id, :manager_id, :project_ids,
    address_attributes: [:street, :number, :postal_code, :city]
```

Parameters: 

`{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jNSKHkHXRr6W8+1vrpg6ZO8QN34zsByq8Hl/dkz0KFR2o4eU61qaHr3mVUQFfMoxKvjxX096N8a5kOPFw4QP5Q==", "building"=>{"project_ids"=>"1b4a46df-62bc-44ec-8915-e0d3b5e8b398", "name"=>"a1", "construction_year"=>"2010", "floors"=>"5", "building_type"=>"single_tenant", "energy_label"=>"A++", "owner_id"=>"98f74ca0-986f-4733-91e6-185a7c7920f5", "manager_id"=>"98f74ca0-986f-4733-91e6-185a7c7920f5", "address_attributes"=>{"street"=>"lane", "number"=>"1", "postal_code"=>"0000aa", "city"=>"somewhere", "id"=>"049e44df-6d0d-4c86-9ea8-34aba5b8d5f8"}}, "commit"=>"Update Building", "id"=>"db66a4fd-768b-4315-a4e9-3e7aa04d9cdf"}`

The id that is unpermitted is:
`"id"=>"db66a4fd-768b-4315-a4e9-3e7aa04d9cdf"`

I tried adding it as follows (also in different ways like building_id), but it doesn't remove the message.

```
permit_params :id, :name, :construction_year, :floors, :building_type, :energy_label, :owner_id, :manager_id, :project_ids,
    address_attributes: [:street, :number, :postal_code, :city]
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the building `:id`, it's the `address_attributes` that should have the `:id` added.

So in `building.rb`:

```
permit_params :name, :construction_year, :floors, :building_type, :energy_label, :owner_id, :manager_id, :project_ids,
    address_attributes: [:id, :street, :number, :postal_code, :city]
```

Answer (score 0):

add `:id` to your nested attributes

```
permit_params :id, :name, :construction_year, :floors, :building_type, :energy_label, :owner_id, :manager_id, :project_ids,
    address_attributes: [:id, :street, :number, :postal_code, :city]
```

Answer (score 0):

add :id to address_attributes

```
permit_params :name, :construction_year, :floors, :building_type, :energy_label, :owner_id, :manager_id, :project_ids,
    address_attributes: [:id, :street, :number, :postal_code, :city]
```